# How to return the attribute value from an array in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a function which returns me a Array Objects, and I want to return the ID in an array (as I can have many objects), of which each object has one. Here's what I have tried.

```
 iban_obj.map{ |id| id },
 iban_obj.select(&:id)
```

Here is my iban_obj:

```
    [{"url"=>"xxxx.json",
  "id"=>360081391060,
  "title"=>"Test Macro",
  "active"=>true,
  "updated_at"=>"2021-11-22T13:15:06Z",
  "created_at"=>"2021-11-19T16:52:00Z",
  "position"=>10002,
  "description"=>"{{ iban }} {{ phone_number }} {{ email }}",
  "actions"=>
   [{"field"=>"comment_value_html",
     "value"=>
  "restriction"=>nil}]
```

Desired Result:

```
id_array = [360081391060]
```

Comment: `iban_obj.map{ |data| data['id'] }`

Comment: _"Here's what I have tried"_ – try to approach your problem more systematically. What kind of objects does the array contain? Do the objects even respond to `id`? Figure out how to fetch the ID from one object, then apply that code to `map`.

Answer (score 0):

`id_array = iban_obj.map { |obj| obj['id'] }`

When you call `#map` each whole object will be passed in. From there you have to just select the proper key like you would from any hash.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dig method too..

```
banking_customer.map{ |customer| customer.dig('id') }
```